# How/where to specify number of Akka Actors?

Tags: configuration, akka

I have perused much of the core Akka documentation, and particularly the [Configuration guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html), and even Googled. I am trying to see where/how I can specify that I want, say, 20 `FizzActor` instances in my actor system, or, say, 500 `BuzzActor` instances. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you need to initialize them manually, of course you can use some more sophisticated and configuration based factory pattern. Keep in mind that each actor on the same hierarchy level needs to have unique name.

Beside that you can take benefit of the routing pattern with auto initialized routes.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/routing.html

> This type of router actor comes in two distinct flavors:
>
> Pool - The router creates routees as child actors and removes them
>   from the router if they terminate.

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /parent/router1 {
    router = round-robin-pool
    nr-of-instances = 5
  }
}
```

But it might be not exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @hicolour (+1) - can you give some examples of a more sophisticated factory/configugration for creating actors. Accoridng to [this HelloAkka example](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/hello-akka-java8#code/src/main/java/HelloAkka.java) creating actors is a piecemeal process: `ActorRef greeter = system.actorOf(Props.create(Greeter.class), "greeter")`... thanks again!